# Lightweight Razor editor with auto completion?

Tags: razor, editor, sublimetext2, notepad++, intellisense

Are there any lightweight editors for Razor templates (.cshtml) with auto completion support?

or any plugins for Notepad++, Sublime Text 2, etc with Razor auto completion support?

Answer (score 2):

SynWrite editor supports Razor lexer since last beta. No special auto-completion for Razor besides usual HTML completion (Razor is just HTML based, HTML completion works for html parts).

Comment: SynWrite not installed Razor and many other lexers by default, they are located in Addons Manager "Install" list.

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++, you could combine the following two tips and get close to Visual Studio-like editing:

[Syntax Highlighting](http://www.mattblodgett.com/2007/11/notepad-tip-syntax-highlighting-for.html)

[Enable autocompletion](http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/how-to-enable-intellisense-in-notepad/)